# Ng-repeat in detached object (Semantic UI Modal)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, semantic-ui, detach

I am trying to get the Modal component from the Semantic UI library (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html) to work on my website. The problem is though, that to get the modal to work and display correctly it detaches itself from the DOM as explained in the documentation:

> A modal can be included anywhere on the page. On initialization a modal's current size will be cached, and the element will be detached from the dom and moved inside a dimmer.

This causes the ng-repeat inside the modal contents to break, and when you think about it, it's kind of obvious. The ng-repeat cannot access the DOM's controller because the parent element got detached from the DOM.

I need to find a way to be able to render the ng-repeat inside the modal component and still keep its functionality like it is now. There is a setting to change the `detachable` property to false, but this causes the Modal to be displayed incorrectly and it influences the design of the page.

I really hope there is some kind of solution for this, because I'm really puzzled as to what to do.

Would it be possible to create a separate controller for the modal component itself? Will it keep itself attached? And if so how could I communicate between the page's main controller and the little modal controller?

**Here is the code for my current modal**
This entire block gets detached from DOM.

```
<div class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Choose profile picture
    </div>
    <div class="content">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <h4 class="header">Choose a default</h4>
                <div class="ui eight doubling cards">

                    <div ng-repeat="img in defaultImages2" class="card">
                        <div class="dimmable image">
                            <div class="ui inverted dimmer">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="center">
                                        <div class="ui teal button" ng-click="">Choose</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/profile/{{img}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="ui horizontal divider">
                Or
            </div>
            <div class="ui teal labeled icon button">
                Upload your own
                <i class="upload icon"></i>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
        <div class="ui button">OK</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can either pass in `scope` to the modal options if it allows, or use a separate controller and use `broadcast` to pass the `scope` in from the other controller to have access in the modal.

Comment: Is it possible for you to illustrate it with a few lines of code? Also as far as separate controller goes, I tried this `<div class="ui modal" ng-controller="SmallModalController">` but the inner ng-repeat doesn't seem to be able to access the scope. I'll add some code to my original question.

Comment: I don't have time currently to illustrate it in a plunkr, but you can search for some plunkr $broadcast examples. Also, I know you're using semantic-ui lib, but there's many angular-modules that automatically include this functionality for modals. http://ngmodules.org/